# Highcharts 3D with rCharts

Tags: r, highcharts, 3d, rcharts

Highcharts 3D with rCharts

Can rCharts be made to work with the 3D module of Highcharts? Below is an example of Highcharts 3D:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/

## Error

The error that appears for my example code below is:

```
Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : ‘zAxis’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Highcharts”
```

## Example Code

Here is the example code I'm using:

```
library(rCharts)

# Based on example from: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/V37Vv/light/
plotData <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,4,4,7,7,8), 
                       y = c(1,1,1,3,6,5,2,1,1,1), 
                       z = c(1,2,5,2,4,7,8,3,5,5), 
                       category=rep(c("A", "B"), 5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

xLabel <- "X" 
yLabel <- "Y" 
zLabel <- "Z" 
title <- "Title"

if (is.null(rownames(plotData))){
    rownames(plotData) <- as.character(1:nrow(plotData))
}

# HighCharts point name
plotData$name <- rownames(plotData)

# Scatter plot
h1 <- rCharts::Highcharts$new()
h1$setLib("libraries/widgets/highcharts")

h1$chart(renderTo="container",
         margin=c(150, 75, 75, 75),
         type='scatter',
         options3d=list(enabled=TRUE,
                        alpha=20,
                        beta=30,
                        depth=200))

h1$title(text=title)
h1$xAxis(title=list(enabled=TRUE, text=xLabel))
h1$yAxis(title=list(enabled=TRUE, text=yLabel))
h1$zAxis(title=list(enabled=TRUE, text=zLabel))

# Divide the dataset, split by category and put into list() format
# From: http://rcharts.io/viewer/?5735146#.VF6NS4W1Fy4
series <- lapply(split(plotData, plotData$category), function(x) {
    res <- lapply(split(x, rownames(x)), as.list)
    names(res) <- NULL
    return(res)
})

invisible(sapply(series, function(x) {
    h1$series(data=x, type="scatter", name=x[[1]]$category)
}
))

h1$legend(enabled=FALSE)

# Force circle markers and change size
h1$plotOptions(scatter=list(marker=list(symbol='circle', radius=6)))

h1$tooltip(formatter = "#! function() { return this.point.name + ', ' + 
           this.series.name + ', ' + this.x + ', ' + this.y; } !#")

# Enable exporting
h1$exporting(enabled=TRUE)

# Set name
h1$set(dom=xLabel)

# Print chart
print(h1)
#h1$show("inline")
```

## Highcharts/rCharts Files Folder: libraries/widgets/highcharts

This folder contains a config.yml:

### config.yml

```
highcharts:
  jshead:
    - js/jquery-1.7.min.js
    - js/highcharts.js
    - js/highcharts-more.js
    - js/exporting.js
    - js/highcharts-3d.js
  cdn:
    jshead:
      - "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"
      - "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"
      - "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"
      - "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"
      - "http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"
```

### js/ folder

The js/ folder has the files referenced in the config.yml

### layouts/ folder

The layouts/ folder has chart.html

#### chart.html

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($){
        $(function () {
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({{{ chartParams }}});
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: As I can see from the [source code](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/R/Highcharts.R) - zAxis isn't supported. Try to remove: `h1$zAxis(title=list(enabled=TRUE, text=zLabel))` line. It may happen that you can't change zAxis, but charts will work anyway.

Comment: Commenting out that line results in a 2D plot, which is not the intended result.

Comment: Then probably rCharts lib doesn't support 3D Highcharts. Do you have generated Highcharts code/options? To check where may be problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now there is another highcharts wrapper for R. Include the 3d module. Example here: http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts-api.html.

Code

```
data(citytemp)

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = citytemp$month) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "London", data = citytemp$london) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Other city",
                data = (citytemp$tokyo + citytemp$london)/2)  %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column",
           options3d = list(enabled = TRUE, beta = 15, alpha = 15))

hc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think 3D charts are available in rCharts, hence the error on the nonexistent z axis.

Instead you have to use the package [rthreejs](https://github.com/bwlewis/rthreejs) based on Ramnathv's [htmlwidget](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets) package which also works in Rmarkdown and Shiny.

```
devtools::install_github("ramnathv/htmlwidgets")
devtools::install_github("bwlewis/rthreejs")

libs <- c("htmlwidgets", "threejs")
lapply(libs, library, character.only=TRUE)
```

[Example](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_threejs.html) on htmlwidget galery